# Removing blank lines while creating file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that creates files for each line of a CSV file. However, somehow a blank line is being added to the end of the newly created file.

**Code:**

```
 with open(fullCSV, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            csvList = list(reader)

        for item in csvList:
            if not os.path.exists(tempLoc + item[0]):
                os.mkdir(tempLoc + item[0])
            with open(tempLoc + item[0] + r"\prm.263", "w+") as f:
                csv.writer(f).writerow(item[1:])
            f.close
```

Is there some way I can strip the blank line on creation?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

Here is the sample of 1 of the output files that is being created
[image]

Here is the CSV file its reading
[image]

Comment: (With the `with open() as`, you don't have to close the file at the end manually)

Comment: @Fukiyel good to know, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want to strip it? It's a pretty common convention for *nix-like systems to use a new line character as the terminator of every line. Depending on what you are doing with the files, getting rid of it could potentially cause issues with other tools.

Comment: @PAckerman yes, having the blank line in the newly created files is breaking other scripts when they are reading the file(s).

Comment: (The csv reader is already there for you to iterate over it. No need to make a list out of it for just doing that.)

Comment: Did you already try `csv.writer(f).writerow(item[1:].strip())`?

Comment: Yeah I agree with @SpghttCd, `csv.writer(open('foo.csv', 'w')).writerow('foo bar'.split())` doens't inlcude  a blank line at the of the file, it can be the file data.

Comment: @SpghttCd I tried that and got error "list" object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Ah, of course, every row is already a list, too, when using csv module... Then you may try perhaps `csv.writer(f).writerow(','.join([i.strip() for i in item[1:]]))`

Comment: Can you post the sample data as text instead of screenshots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the csv module. You can see that there is no way to get rid of the end of line character from the output of `writerow()`. After all, the csv module assume you can repeatedly write rows:

```
 writer.writerow(row1)
 writer.writerow(row2)
 ...
```

so emitting a newline on *every row output* is necessary to make it work. But your question is to remove the newline at end of file. So you can consider adding an extra step in between: (using Python 3 io module)

```
with open(tempLoc + item[0] + r"\prm.263", "w+") as f:
    g = io.StringIO()
    csv.writer(g).writerow(item[1:])
    f.write(g.getvalue().rstrip())
```

Above, we make a `StringIO` as file-like object for `csv.writer()` and ask the writer to write to the buffer instead of the file. After you finish writing all the rows, we read the buffer by `g.getvalue()` and then strip out the whitespaces (i.e., the newline) at the end, and write to the file.

If you're interested, this is what the csv module will give you for each row:

```
>>> import io
>>> f = io.StringIO()
>>> import csv
>>> csv.writer(f).writerow([1,2,3,4])
9
>>> f.getvalue()
'1,2,3,4\r\n'
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I will award the bounty when the timer expires. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

[`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) by default uses the [`excel`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/csv.html#csv.excel) dialect, which has a `'\r\n'` as lineterminator.

If you really don't want any line terminator, you can override that with the `lineterminator` parameter to `csv.writer()`:

```
csv.writer(f, lineterminator='').writerow(item[1:])
```

Since you only write 1 single line in each file, you will not have an issue with all original lines ending up concatenated in 1 single line in your output.

Your sample code rewritten:

```
with open(fullCSV, 'r') as finput:
    for item in csv.reader(finput):
        if not os.path.exists(tempLoc + item[0]):
            os.mkdir(tempLoc + item[0])
        with open(tempLoc + item[0] + r"\prm.263", "w+") as foutput:
            csv.writer(foutput, lineterminator='').writerow(item[1:])
```